# Process lines of text with bash

Tags: bash, cut

I'm saving a file with dates and file names with this structure:

```
date1 name1
date2 name2
...
dateN nameN
```

Afterwards I'm reading the file with the while command and trying to compare if the date field is equal to a date given. If the date is the same, I'm saving the name and then printing it.

```
while read line
do
    if [ ‘$($line | cut -c 1-10)’ == ‘$(date +%Y-%m-%d)’ ]
    then
        name=$($linea | cut -c 12-100)
    fi
    echo $name
done < archivos.txt
```

After executing the script, the console is giving me every date into the file with the 'command not found' error.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: shouldn't `echo $name` be in the if-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is interesting, but it may be easier to skip the use of a `while` loop and use `awk` all together, giving the date as parameter:

```
awk '$1~d {print $2}' d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) archivos.txt
```

- `$1~d {print $2}` if the first field matches the date given, print the 2nd field.
- `d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` pass today's date to `awk`.

#### Sample

```
$ cat a
2014-01-28 hello
2014-01-28 byetwo
2014-02-28 bye
2014-01-29 bye

$ awk '$1~d {print $2}' d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) a
hello
byetwo
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't use the awk command yet. I have a couple of questions about this.

When I use the command in the console, it prints the name, but when I take the same command and try to execute it on a script, it returns the following errors: 
    line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
    line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: The other question is how can I save the result on a variable instead of printing it? 

Many thanks, fedorqui!

Comment: Egunon! Mmm strange, the EOF you are commenting shouldn't appear. Can you check my updated answer? I just print the 2nd field. Regarding the second question, yes, it is possible to save into a variable, but how do you want it? Because eventually it will be an array of values.

Comment: It gives me the same error on the script execution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I cannot guess what the problem is. In case it is regarding how the parameter is given, can you try with the following? `awk -v d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) '$1~d {print $2}' file` . Note that my solution is stand alone, no need to insert it into any of your previous code.

Comment: It failed the same way. I've tried with another awk command and it seemed to work: awk '{ if ($1 == d) name=$2 } END { print name }' d=2014-01-27 archivos.txt

Thanks fedorqui!

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is written, you are trying to execute `$line` as a command.  You need to use `echo` or `printf` to write the line to stdout instead:

```
$(printf %s "$line" | cut -c 1-10)
```

Comment: Tried this one but it gives me "cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence" error.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because your script can't find the date command. This gives you two options.

**Option 1: Locate the date binary and give the full path**

Run "whereis date" in your command prompt and it should output something liket his
 date: /bin/date /usr/share/man/man1/date.1.gz
You can then either change

```
$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

to

```
$(/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

**Option 2: Export a path where the binary should be looked for**

The reason date can't be found is because it's not in the script's PATH variable. You can either just add /bin/ to PATH or have the same as you have in your shell. Run
 echo $PATH
in your shell and it should output something liket his

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

What you then can do then is to set the scripts PATH variable to the same thing so it would look like this:

```
export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
while read line
do
    if [ ‘$($line | cut -c 1-10)’ == ‘$(date +%Y-%m-%d)’ ]
    then
        name=$($linea | cut -c 12-100)
    fi
    echo $name
done < archivos.txt
```